# Life on a planet orbiting a blue giant

Tags: planets, science-in-society

Would it be possible for life to evolve on a planet orbiting a blue giant? If so, what kinds of life forms? Could some sort of humans evolve there? How long would it take?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No

Compared to Sun-like stars, there are obvious differences in spectrum and luminosity, but those are not the main reasons why blue giant systems are extremely unlikely to harbor life. While a Sun-like star can burn stably for billions of years, giants will burn out in no more than just a few million years. This period of time is too short for the planets to form a stable crust, let alone develop life.

For the Solar system and Earth, by comparison, it took several hundred million years for Earth to cool down and heavy meteorite bombardment to stop. Then it took another 3 billion years for life to evolve from the simplest forms to complex multicellular organisms.

[O-type star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O-type_star#Characteristics)

Sun-type (G class) and smaller (K class) stars are considered to be the most promising to have life in their systems.

Comment: Is there any type of star other than the Sun that could allow for life to evolve?

Comment: @LivNelson Sounds like a good question to ask, or even edit this one into.

Comment: There is evidence of life being on Earth even as far back as [4.28 billion years ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earliest_known_life_forms). It could be conceivable that life can form on an earth-like planet orbiting a B type star, just don't expect anything more than simple single celled organisms.

Comment: What if a race of human-like creatures can terraform a planet? Would it be possible to pick one orbiting a blue giant? Would it be possible to stabilise the crust, or would the star make it impossible? Would luminosity be a problem?

Comment: The star would not affect the planet's crust, so if there is the way to artificially create a "mature" lithosphere, go for it. What concerns me the most is the immaturity of whole system - many asteroids and [Planetesimals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetesimal) are still on very unstable orbits. Imagine you did all the good work - only for a [Theia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theia_(planet))-type planet to destroy everything.

Comment: @Alexander I once read that no planets can form around O and B giants as they give of intense IV radiation, destroying the proto planetary disk. However I would have to search for a source on this one, so take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

There may be another possibly. A planet or moon thrown from another system could be captured by a blue giant star. The debris could be cleared by a more massive planet orbiting closer to the blue star. There are lots of possibilities. That still doesn’t give life much time to evolve though...